# Try set background dashed line but result - underscore

Tags: android, shapes

I try set dashed line to item

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke
        android:color="#100901"
        android:dashWidth="10px"
        android:dashGap="10px"
        android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

And in androidstudio I see all correct. But in real app I see not dashed line and underscore.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a layer-list drawable instead.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:bottom="2dp"
    android:left="-2dp"
    android:right="-2dp"
    android:top="-2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
        <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="#100901"
            android:dashGap="10px"
            android:dashWidth="10px" />
    </shape>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/triangleup"
    android:tileMode="repeat"
    android:tint="@color/lightAccent"/>
```

here triangleup is your image of dash line.

Happy coding!!